# Post an image to Facebook from the iPhone camera library in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following method to post a photo to Facebook. It works fine, however the image is set like this:         `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/image.png"];`

I'd like to have the user select the image from their iPhone camera folder instead. How would I go about doing this - retrieving an image from the Photo Album and sending it from this method?

thanks for any help

```
- (void)apiGraphUserPhotosPost {
    [self showActivityIndicator];
    currentAPICall = kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost;
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Download a sample photo
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/image.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   img, @"picture",
                                   nil];
    [img release];

    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: are you done with selecting image from gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are done with selecting image from gallery?

if not then please follow the steps [here in this blog entry](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/), once you got the image, then simply do this way:

```
UIImage *img  = yourImageFromLibrary;
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   img, @"picture",
                                   nil];
... //rest of code
```

Comment: I'm able to launch the image picker select the image. how do I go about saving it as an object to then send to FB. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use the `UIImagePickerController`. Take a look at the Apple docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

P.S.: `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` is not a good idea for non `file:` URLs. It is synchronous. Rather use async API like `-[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`